# Statically pre-render most popular queries with NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using NextJS to pre-render pages of the format:

```
./pages/folder/[variable].js
```

I have a set of some ~ 8000 possible values for [variable], so it is not practically feasible to statically generate all 8000 of these pages. Because of this, I use **getSeverSideProps()** whenever this page is loaded. Here is what that looks like:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { variable } = context.params
    const { res } = context;
    // Caches response for 15 minutes on the server side
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', `s-maxage=900, stale-while-revalidate`)

    const { data } = await axios.get(url + variable);
    return { props : {data} }
}
```

In spite of there being over ~ 8000 values, the top 50 values contain ~90% of queries.

Is there any way to statically pre-render these 50 values with something like **getStaticPaths()** and **getStaticProps()**, such that these particular 50 queries are faster to load?

Secondarily, and less concerning, is that the list of the most common requests changes slightly over time. If there was a solution to dynamically determine this list of 50 values, that would be ideal (although is not strictly necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the concept of Incremental Static Regeneration in Nextjs:

> Next.js allows you to create or update static pages after you’ve built your site. Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) enables you to use static-generation on a per-page basis, without needing to rebuild the entire site. With ISR, you can retain the benefits of static while scaling to millions of pages.

and here is how it works:

```
// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It may be called again, on a serverless function, if
// the path has not been generated.
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
  // on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
  return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

Don't forget that you still need to define `getStaticProps` function on your page.

Here is the official Documentation about [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)

Comment: Beautiful! I somehow completely glossed over that. Thanks :)